# how to display product attribute in product list Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, theme, blocks, product-attribute

I'm trying to display size shoes attribute for each product in product list (something like a native configurable swatches ) , But I got all sizes on the top of the page instead of getting them under each product name . **Is there any way to create dynamic block and append it for each product or another alternative ?**

I create a module and I'm using an observer to handle the collection , I don't like to have a bunch of code in list.phtml

my code is the following : 
observer.php

```
<?php  
class Campany_Swatches_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract  
{  
public function productListCollectionLoadAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)  
{  
        $collection = $observer->getCollection();
        $helper = Mage::helper('Campany_swatches');
        $products = $collection->getItems();

        /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        foreach ($products as $product) {
             $helper->getAttributes($product);

         }
    }
}
```

helper Data.php

```
<?php
class Campany_Swatches_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    private $_html;

    public function getAttributes($_product = false)
    {
        if($_product->isConfigurable()){
        //get attributes 
           $attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product) ;
           if(count($attributes)){
                foreach($attributes as $att){
                    $pAtt = $att->getProductAttribute();
                    //get the  product children
                    $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
                    $frontValues =array();

                    if ($pAtt->getFrontendLabel() == "Shoe Size"){ 
                        foreach($allProducts as $p){
                             //check stock, status, ...
                             //do not show unsaleable options
                        if(!$p->isSaleable()) continue; 
                            $out=$p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName()); 
                            $frontValues[$out]=$out; 
                        } 

                        $this->_html = '<div class="shoeSize">';
                        $this->_html .= '<ul class="configurable-swatch-list configurable-swatch-size_clothes ulshoeSize clearfix">';
                        $this->_html .='<li class="swatch-label">';
                        $this->_html .= implode('</li><li class="swatch-label">', $frontValues);
                        $this->_html .='</li> </ul></div>';
                    } 
                }
            }
        }

    return $this->_html;

    }
```

Comment: Is the product attribute's able to be used in product listing "used_in_product_listing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observer.php code does not render the html to list.phtml proper

If you observer code have create perform issue on list page.
Basically code :

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
             $helper->getAttributes($product);

         }
```

**create main issue for all collection twice,one at observer and another is list.phtml.**

It will be good call  `Mage::helper('Campany_swatches')->getAttribute($_product);` at list.phtml inside foreack loop of products ,this one line code is make all solution.

Comment: You ate welcome